# How can I create a program to track the blocks created on Solana and send a notification if one isnt created

Tags: block

I wan't to create a program that can notify me if a block isn't created for 5 or so seconds. Essentially, a personal Solana down detector. Ideally a notification via telegram mentioning "no block created" or something along those line

Apologies for my naivety, I'm new to this so still figuring out where the best place to start is, any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks pxl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you just need to poll some RPC server and make sure that some piece of data is updating regularly. You can use:

- transaction count with `getTransactionCount` https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransactioncount
- block height with `getBlockHeight` https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getblockheight
- blockhash with `getLatestBlockhash` https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getlatestblockhash

There already exists a program to do exactly this called `watchtower`. You can find the source code at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/tree/master/watchtower and tweak it as you wish!